# I want to get a value from another window?(python, tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanted to get a value from another window so i saved the value using xlsxwriter and got it using pandas but the problem is that i get the value not after the that window is destroyed but after the main window is closed?
can you tell me how i get the value without closing the main window??

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal working example? What value are you talking about? Is it a `Label` or an `Entry`?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a helpful link with a simple solution to what you are attempting to accomplish. Basically, you need one frame to accept a variable as input and the other frame to 'get' the variable from the first frame.

https://www.code4example.com/python/tkinter/tkinter-passing-variables-between-windows/

** copied here from source for simplicity **

```
    from tkinter import *

    class Frames(object):
        def newFrame(self):
            newwin = Toplevel(root)
            newwin.title('New Window')
            newwin.geometry("200x100") 
            newwin.resizable(0, 0)
    
            #getting parameter via query var
            display = Label(newwin, text="Hello, " + self.query.get()) 
            display.pack()


        def mainFrame(self,root):
            self.query = StringVar() #passing parameter via query var
    
            root.title('Open Window!!!')
            root.geometry("200x200") 
            root.resizable(0, 0)
            button1 =Button(root, text ="Open and Send New Window", command =self.newFrame)
            button1.place(x = 15, y = 25, width=170, height=25)

            entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=self.query)
            entry1.place(x = 50, y = 75, width=100, height=25)


    root = Tk()
    app = Frames()
    app.mainFrame(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: make sure, that that window open only one time. looks like the program will bei crash if you open too much windows

Comment: This was taken from the source (link in post) as a minimally viable example of what the OP appeared to be attempting. The number of windows was not specified in the original question.

Comment: you present an app, where you can open another windows. it does't matter who was written that code, it doen't answer his question

Comment: the code presented passes a value from a window to another window and displays the value that was passed. this certainly answers the question, imho. could you please provide an example that does it in a different way?

Comment: I tried it but it won't work. Actually I want the value on my main window.
For Example:
I access the other window with a button and choose a value on the other window.
now I want that value to work on my main window I tried hard but I couldnt get it
And Actually I made the two windows in separate scripts

Comment: @MuneebKhan could you update your original post to provide an example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: I go it by saving my value to a database and then getting it back through a button its not the nice way but it works fine for my project.

Comment: If you could tell me any method to block the window
For Example: I want to my window to be locked on the screen until its destroyed or closed. and the mouse can not do anything before closing it.
Is there any simple way to do that????